# AUTO:42003 Orthographic projection outside valid area

Tags: coordinate-system, geotools

When running the following code to reproject a epsg:4326 countries file to orthographic:

```
newCRS = CRS.decode("AUTO:42003,1,-100,45");
mapFrame.getMapContent().getViewport().setCoordinateReferenceSystem(newCRS);
```

The following error occurs:
WARNING: Possible use of "Orthographic" projection outside its valid area.
Latitude 112°43.8'S is out of range (±90°).

Does anyone know how to get the orthographic projection to work?

Comment: you probably have your latitude and longitude switched, but we'd need to see the value of getViewPort's bbox before you transform it

Comment: Bounds before reprojection: ReferencedEnvelope[-180.0 : 180.00000190734863, -90.0 : 83.57026863098145].  After: ReferencedEnvelope[-180.0 : 180.00000190734858, -112.73017238719122 : 106.30044101817266]

Comment: looks like a long/lat box but should probably be a lat/long one - need to see the WKT of the original CRS to be sure

Comment: GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
  DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
    SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
  PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
  UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
  AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
  AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]ReferencedEnvelope[-180.0 : 180.00000190734858, -112.73017238719122 : 106.30044101817266]

Comment: To:  PROJCS["WGS 84 / Auto Orthographic", 
  GEOGCS["WGS84(DD)", 
    DATUM["WGS84", 
      SPHEROID["WGS84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
    AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH]], 
  PROJECTION["Orthographic"], 
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
  UNIT["m", 1.0], 
  AXIS["Easting", EAST], 
  AXIS["Northing", NORTH]]

Answer (score 1):

An [Orthographic Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection_in_cartography) is of a hemisphere so if you try to display the whole world (as you seem to be) it will throw a `ProjectionExcpetion` (Point outside of hemisphere of projection) at least in recent versions.

But you seem to be hitting an earlier issue that your input bounding box is almost square (`-180.0 : 180.00000190734858, -112.73017238719122 : 106.30044101817266`) and GeoTools is complaining that the Earth isn't that tall (-112 is clearly below the South Pole (-90)) and so throws an earlier error than I'm seeing. With a smaller dataset your code works fine.

[image]